# Android Fragment ViewPager not updating after setting adapter

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I have an animation which takes two Fragments that represent inflated layouts. The primary layout the user interacts with is a ViewPager. Well this ViewPager is updated on a regular basis dependent upon user action.

The issue is, when the animation occurs the Fragments are recreated, thus the ViewPager is recreated, which is great because the animation is intended as a loading scene. When the primary fragment shows up, the pages of the ViewPager are empty? They remain empty until I gesture back and forth to find them "magically" load it would seem...

Any help would be great.

Fragment of the Primary View ViewPager(Inner Class):

```
    /**
 * A fragment representing the front of the card.
 */
public static class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment { 

    public CardFrontFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView;

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dashboard, container, false);

        TextView    textviewLocation    = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_location);
        TextView    textviewConditions  = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_points);
        ViewPager   viewPagerDashboard  = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_Dashboard);

        if(overviewData != null) {

            textviewLocation.setText(overviewData.getLocation());
            textviewPoints.setText(overviewData.getPoints());

            viewPagerDashboard.setAdapter(adapterSectionsPager);
            viewPagerDashboard.invalidate();
            adapterSectionsPager.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Now everytime the animation occurs, when the primary fragment comes around, it is recreated to what you see above.

Here is the Adapter for the ViewPager:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return DashboardSectionFragment.create
                (uiContext, position, overviewData, moreData, moreData, moreData);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 4 total pages:
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section_1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section_2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section_3).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_section_4).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

So then the adapter is set and all the UI work is done which consist of a ListView for the
first page.

So what leaves me confused is that when the application is first launched, the animation happens immidiatley and everything works the pages are added and can be seen. But when the user presses a button and it fires the exact same process the ViewPager seems to update but no push the updates out? I can see the tab strip of what should be pages but the pages do not load until they are cycled through by physical gestures...

Any help would be much appreciated.